# Comparing two dates having different years

Tags: php

i want to compare last date on my form with current date, but it comparing only date and month not year. What can I do compare dates having different years?

1.db.inc.php

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME','ftender');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

?>
```

2.fun.inc.php

```
<?php

include_once'db.inc.php';

        function connect()
        {
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ftender');


    if($con!=true)
    {
        echo 'Connection failed';
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_select_db($con,'ftender');
    }

        }

        function close()
        {
            $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ftender');


    if($con!=true)
    {
        echo 'Connection failed';
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_select_db($con,'ftender');
    }

            mysqli_close($con);
        }

        function clos (){
            mysql_close();
        }


        function query(){
            $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ftender');


    if($con!=true)
    {
        echo 'Connection failed';
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_select_db($con,'ftender');
    }   
        $date=date("m/d/Y");
    $q="SELECT * FROM adtender where lastdate>='$date' group by tendername";
            $myData=mysqli_query($con,$q);
            while($record=mysqli_fetch_array($myData,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                echo '<option value="' . $record['tendername'] . '">' . $record['tendername'] . '</option>';
            }
        }

        function fill(){
            $myID=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adtender");
            while($r=mysql_fetch_array($myID)){
                echo '<option value="' .$r['tenderid'] .'">' . $r['tenderid'] . '</option>';
            }
        }

?>
```

3.company.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
    include_once 'fun.inc.php';
    connect();

?>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 360px)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 480px)" href="landscape.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 481px)" href="desktop.css">


<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
rel="Stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
<script>
                    function myFunction(){
                        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= x;

                        var formInput = document.getElementById("theInput").value;
                        document.getElementById("newText").innerHTML= formInput;

                        var formFee = document.getElementById("theFee").value;
                        document.getElementById("newFee").innerHTML= formFee;
                    }
                    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="banner">

  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>

   <li  align="center"><a href="welcome.php">मुख पृष्ठ</br>  &nbsp; </a></li>
  <li align="center"><a href="adtender.php">निविदा जोड़े</br>  &nbsp; </a></li>
  <li align="center"><a href="company.php">निविदा के लिए आवेदन करें </a></li>
   <li align="center"><a href="subtenderprice.php">निविदा मूल्य दर्ज करें </a></li>
  <li align="center"><a href="adqp.php">कोटेशन मूल्य दर्ज करें </a></li>
  <li align="center"><a href="t1.php">उत्पन्न कार्य आदेश </a></li>
  <li align="center"><a href="viewtender.php">सभी निविदा</br>  &nbsp;</a></li>
  <li align="center"><a href="vieworder.php">सभी कार्य आदेश </a></li>
  <li align="center"><a href="../ftender.php">लोग आउट</br>  &nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div id="content">
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

  <h2 align="center">निविदा के लिए आवेदन करें </h2>
                <form action="comreg.php" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
                    <table width="400" align="center" border="0" style="border-color:#FFF;" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td>निविदा का नाम</td>

                        <td>
                            <select style="width:150px;" name="tendername" id="mySelect" onchange='choice();'>
                            <?php query() ?>
                            </select>
                            <?php close() ?>
                        </td>   </tr>
                    <tr><td>कंपनी का नाम</td>
                        <td>
                        <input style="width:150px;" type="text" name="companyname" id="theInput">
                        </td>

                </tr><tr><td>कंपनी का पता</td>
                        <td>
                        <input style="width:150px;" type="text" name="companyaddr" id="theInput">
                        </td>   



                    </tr>
                    <tr colspan="6">
                        <td colspan="6" align="center">
                        <!--<input type="button" onclick="myFunction();" value="view">-->
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

                </form><script>
            $("#mySelect").change(function(){
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                $("#theFee").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"))
            }); 
    </script>

  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


    </div>

  <div id="bottom"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>

 <div id="footer">

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This coding is comparing 2 dates correctly without considering year.

Comment: `date("m/d/Y")` is not a valid mysql date format. What is the column type? If it is not something like `datetime` you should switch to that. Now it looks like you are comparing strings instead of dates.

Comment: try to use `BETWEEN` in your query.

Comment: The HTML code is totally irrelevant for the question and the same is 3/4 of the PHP code you posted. Please provide a [mcve]. If the question is related to MySQL then add it as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL `date()` and `month()` functions.

For example:

```
...where day(lastdate) >= day('$date') and month(lastdate) >= month('$date')
```

And if your date is in string format you can use `substring()` function.

For example: "12/12/2016" (dd/mm/yyyy)

To extract the day: `substring('$date',0,2);`

To extract the month: `substring('$month',3,2);`

The `substring` arguments are: `(string, position, length)`.

To learn more about `substring()` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: sir this solution is not working where our mysql data type for lastdate is text

Comment: Hi! I've updated the answer to work with text (strings).

Comment: what is the value of $date and $month here

Comment: The parts you extracted from your $date var in php.